# Pass ID to another URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Looking to achieve the following with a rewrite:

www.example.com/sub/details/**A12345** rewrites to -> www.example.com/sub/processing.php?id=**A12345**

I have the following, but apparently this isn't working out:

```
RewriteRule ^details/(\d*)$ http://www.example.com/sub/processing.php?id=%1
```

Comment: Where is your htaccess located ?

Comment: @JustinIurman it currently resides in example.com/sub/

Comment: `(\d*)` means "only digits", but you're using letter A, maybe you need `(.*)`?

Comment: Good tip @Lashane  I'm horrible at rewrites! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (located in `sub` folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/

# redirect /sub/processing.php?id=XXX to /sub/details/XXX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /processing\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ details/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /sub/details/XXX to /sub/processing.php?id=XXX
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)$ processing.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Note: you can comment/remove those 2 lines if you want to keep both format active

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /processing\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ details/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I only needed the last RewriteRule, but thank you so much Justin! Seriously was losing my mind! Thanks man!

Comment: Actually did end up needing both of them, bonus points to you sir!